# JPQL query using a foreign key

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I have players and game tables and i'm trying to get the players they has played in a specific time frame so i tried to write the query to the game table since it has the player name as a fk from the player entity but that hasn't work and the error is The state field path 'g.userName' cannot be resolved to a valid type.

```
String q1 =
    " select g.userName from Game g "
        + "where g.gameStart between '2019-11-10 00:00:00' and '2019-11-11 00:00:00'";
```

```
@Entity
@Table()
public class Game {

@Column() public Timestamp timestamp;
@Column() public Timestamp gameStart;
@Column() public Timestamp gameEnd;
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn())
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "QID")
@Column()
public Map<Question, Boolean> playerAnswers = new LinkedHashMap<>();
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int gameID;
@ManyToMany private List<Category> choosenCategories = new ArrayList<>();
@ManyToMany private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
@Column() private int maxNumberOfQuestions;
@ManyToOne() private Player player;

}

//player
@Entity
@Table()
public class Player {
@Id private String userName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "player")
private List<Game> games = new ArrayList<>();

public Player() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`userName` is not a part of `Game` entity. `Player player` is the part of `Game` entity - that's why it throws you the exception about `g.userName` cannot be resolved.

You have to JOIN the `player` entity in you query and get `userName` from `player`.

So try the following:

`SELECT p.userName FROM Game g JOIN g.player p WHERE g.gameStart BETWEEN '2019-11-10 00:00:00' AND '2019-11-11 00:00:00'` (note, that this query is supposed to return `List<String>`)

Comment: thanks it works ! can you help with this one : i want to get all the games for each player with the number of right answers but the right answers are stored in another table ( game_playeranswers) so does it need two joins or how ?

Comment: Yes, you need to have another JOIN the `playeranswers` table.  And yes, that query will have two JOINs in it. There's absolutely nothing wrong with multiple JOINs.

Comment: this is my try `select g.gameId, g.gameStart, g.gameEnd, pl.playerAnswers from Game g join g.playerAnswers pl join g.player p group by p.userName "` but now i have a similar error for the playeranswers because it's a collection

Comment: That's because you have defined `playerAnswers` as a `Map<Question, Boolean> playerAnswers`. You have to define in as a `PlayerAnswer` entity, just like you did with `Player player`, and you also have to specify the relation: `@OneToMany/@ManyToOne/@OneToOne/@OneToMany`. And if you have in your query `pl.playerAnswers` that means that in `PlayerAnswer` entity should be the field `playerAnswers` which I doubt you have.